# BASH loop usage

Tags: linux, bash, loops, logic

I'm currently learning BASH scripting and I have a question about the IF / WHILE / UNTIL loop statement.  I'm trying to learn which one of those is more efficient for checking the contents of a variable for a text-statement, and if not found Can I use the `until` statement to check a variable?  Example usage is like this (I'm using it to check if a system is updated, if not, it updates):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Flush the YUM cache since we've added new directories and repo's
flushcache=$(yum clean all);

# Does our system need to be updated?
checkupdate=$(yum update | grep -i "No Packages marked for Update");

# This will update the system
updatesystem=$(yum update -y);

# Flush the YUM cache, to make sure we get the newest package list
echo "$flushcache";

# Using a LOOP (until-logic), lets make sure we're all updated!
if [[ $checkupdate != "No packages marked for update" ]]
then
    echo "$updatesystem"
else
    echo "They system is already updated";
fi
exit 0;
```

The script exists normally, so that's good, but I'm wanting to know if I'm implementing my new learnz in the most efficient way possible.  Also, will this loop around until `$checkupdate` is a true statement?  I'd love to hear some professional input!

Any help is still help!  Thanks for indulging me!

Comment: I would not use a loop, it will check way too many times and probably use a lop of CPU. Unless you know the loop won't need to be executed a lot in a row, it's better to use a cron job here. - Otherwise a while is indeed the best choice here. A for loopt would be inappropriate (nasty breaks etc).

Comment: agreed, with the alternate idea that O.P. can put a `sleep 300` (seconds) or what-ever at the bottom of a `while` loop. Good luck to all

Comment: Just want to point out that semicolons are not necessary in Bash, nor are exit statements. IIRC Bash will exit with 0 unless you exit with a different number.

Comment: I agree with @Shellfish. `cron` is the best option for your task.